# How to find a small set of vertexes such that all paths in the graph from the start node to the end node will contain at least one of these vertexes

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, set, vertex

In a directed graph with a starting node and an ending node, how to find a small (doesn't have to be smallest) set S of nodes such that every possible path from the starting node to the ending node contains at least one member of set S. Note that the graph may have loops. I know this may be NP-hard.

1. Is there an approximate method to find one or several such S from the graph?
2. Or given a set S, how could I verify that S is a solution? (graph loops seem make the verification very complex.)

Thanks.

PS: this question is similar to Minimum k-path vertex cover problem.

Comment: You should also try to post this question on: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

For (2), you can easily verify that a set has this property by removing all of the nodes in question from the graph and then seeing if there is still an s/t path.  If so, then there must have been some path that did not contain any of the nodes in your set.  If not, then every path must have contained at least one node from the set.

I'm not sure about (1), though.

Hope this helps!